# Can't run HermesJMS from SOAP UI

Tags: stdout, soapui, stderr, hermes-jms

I am trying to run `HermesJMS` from `soapUI 5.2.1` on Windows7 x64
The preferences and path to hermes config are set correctly.

The problem is that I cannot write to `C:` drive. So I had to install SOAPUI and Hermes in alternative places. I have changed hermes_home, java_home and hermes_config to my actual paths. Paths do not contain whitespaces etc. When I run hermes.bat from command prompt, it starts correctly.

However, when I try SoapUI -> Project -> right click -> start HermesJMS - nothing happens. Things are as bad that I even couldn't find anything useful neither in soapui nor in hermes logs.

File structure is as follows:

```
hermes_home = ...\SoapUI-5.2.1\hermesJMS
hermes_config = ...\SoapUI-5.2.1\hermesJMS\cfg
```

Does anyone have an idea what could be going on? Or for a start where can i find stdout and stderr of a script which starts hermes from SoapUI?

Comment: Note that I don't have permissions to run apps as administrator.

Comment: Which JMS vendor are you using?

Comment: @Rao Tibco EMS 5.1.3

Comment: @barsik, are you confirming on behalf of Clergyman?

Comment: @Rao confirming Tibco EMS 5.1.3

Comment: are you connecting to a ems local host or remote host? It requires configuration of ems libraries, user credentials and and ems server url.

Comment: May be it would help if you can show the hermes-cfg.xml file which will have the configuration.

Comment: The problem is not that I can't connect. When I run hermes as standalone application, it runs and connects to needed jms queues. But I need to run in specifically from soapui. So the solution should be somewhere inside soapui libs or scripts, as hermes itself works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps to configure `SoapUI` with `HermesJMS`:

- **Preferences:** In SoapUI tool, go to File -> Preferences -> Tools and set the path for HermesJMS, which is mentioned here in the [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/JMS/getting-started.html). Then, save the preferences.
- **Start HermesJMS**: Now, select your soapui project. Right click -> Start HermesJMS. At this point, a dialog will be shown requesting user to choose for the hermes configuration directory where it looks for the file called `hermes-config.xml`. Default location it looks for is under `{user.home}\.hermes`.

  > You already mentioned hermesJMS is already configured to connect with TIBCO EMS, so you will be having that file on your system.
- **Configuring JMS:** I believe this may not really applicable for you. But, in case if someone is needed, here are the detailed steps provided, citing the documentation. 
  --  Here for [activemq](https://www.soapui.org/documentation/jms/config.html) from the official site.
  --  Here for [TIBCO EMS](http://tibcoadmin.com/tibco/ems/configuring-hermesjms-for-tibco-ems/). And  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24259762/hermesjms-and-tibco), [there](http://www.vanderbist.com/index.php/2009/02/16/how-to-configure-hermesjms-access-for-tibco/). Also find some information relevant to EMS connection issues [here](http://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/SoapUI-HermesJMS-Connecting-to-localhost-EMS-server/m-p/114806).

**Permissions Issue on C Drive:**
There is no constraint from SmartBear that SoapUI needs to be installed in a specific drive on the computer. So, you are free to install the software on your machine where you have the rights to do so.

> Does anyone have an idea what could be going on? Or for a start where can i find stdout and stderr of a script which starts hermes from SoapUI?

Best thing you could do is to go the logs to find what is going on. You can find lot of useful information from the logs when the situation requires. SoapUI logs can be found under {user.home} when you invoked it from windows -> start menu. If you start `SoapUI` from command line (go to `SOAPUI_HOME\bin`) using `soapui.bat` script, then you should be able so the log on the console itself also log files can be found in the same directory where you invoked.

This time the above instruction should resolve your issue.